# Kibana :get count for last 24 hours data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am very new in usage of Kibana
with No knowledge

I want to use Kibana dashboard

my data is in format

```
event._start_seconds
Nov 9, 2023 @ 17:42:26.000
    
event.aggregation.type
agg-l1-suprocessbuildercontainerbasedservices
    
event.created
Nov 9, 2023 @ 17:42:26.396
    
event.id
43926e3d-958a-49fc-8a59-030a47c70ace
```

How can get count of data for last 24hrs ?

json query format

count of data for last 24hrs

After adding [image]

i am seeing below issue
[image]

please let me know if anything missing

[image]